# PhantomJS does not recognize other windows with getWindowHandles() for WebDriver

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, phpunit, phantomjs

When running Selenium tests in PhpStorm that have more than one window, I'm unable to get them working with PhantomJS.

An example is when on one web page, it then clicks a link and needs to verify that the correct URL was opened, so getWindowHandles() is used so that it can then switch to the other opened window. The tests work with every browser, but not phantomjs.  I tried several different things and did a lot of debugging and checked the count of window handles being recognized, and every time phantomjs only showed a count of 1, while when using a browser the count showed 2.

I couldn't really find any info about this anywhere.  Does anyone happen to know if this is a known issue with PhantomJS or if there is something that can be done to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @spdionis I don't think I was ever able to get this working unfortunately.